# Evaluating $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac {3xy^2}{2x^2+9y^4}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \dfrac {3xy^2}{2x^2+9y^4}=
I$$ tried replacing $y$ with $x\cdot m$ and I got $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{3xm^2}{2+9x^2m^4}$ and I thought this limit is $0$, but my teacher told me that this limit is not $0$. What can I do?

Comment: The limit is not zero as there are more paths to approach this limit besides $y=mx$. For example, consider $x=ay^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0) } \dfrac {3xy^2}{2x^2+9y^4}$$
For $y=0$:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0) }  \dfrac {3xy^2}{2x^2+9y^4}=\dfrac {0}{2x^2} = 0$$
For $x=y^2$ we have that:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac {3xy^2}{2x^2+9y^4}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0) }\dfrac {3y^4}{11y^4}=\dfrac {3}{11} \ne 0$$

The limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

To see why the limit doesn't exist, it can be useful define

- $\sqrt 2\,x = u$
- $3y^2=v$

to obtain

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \dfrac {3xy^2}{2x^2+9y^4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\,\lim_{(u,v)\to(0,0)} \dfrac {uv}{u^2+v^2}$$

which is simpler to handle.

Comment: Hi my friend. long time no see! I really missed the time when I asked limit problems on the site and saw your brilliant answers on each one of my posts ;) I learned a lot from them.I hope to see you answering problems on the site again. Thank you for all the helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The limit doesn't exist actually. If $f$ is your function, try to see how behave $f(0,t)$ and $f(t^2,t)$ when $t\to 0$.